# Abelian group is free iff projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

It is well-known that an abelian group is free iff it is projective, which can be easily extended to modules over PID. The standard proof requires the use of Zorn's Lemma/Well-ordering principle. Are there ways of proving this without axiom of choice or anything equivalent? Any hints or proof outlines will be appreciated. Any tools from introductory homological algebra and commutative algebra can be freely used. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Andreas Blass proved in

*Blass, Andreas*, [**Injectivity, projectivity, and the axiom of choice**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1998165), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 255, 31-59 (1979). [ZBL0426.03053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0426.03053).

that the statement "every free abelian group is projective" is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you. How about the converse? We often use the fact that subgroups of free abelian group is free and conclude that projective abelian groups are free. Is the axiom of choice necessary for this?

Comment: @LarrySmith I was wondering that myself, and I don’t know. I’m not an expert, but I would be surprised if it didn’t need at least some weak version of choice. But I wouldn’t be surprised if it only needed something strictly weaker than the full axiom of choice.